# The default changelist of WebStorm take a long time to update

Tags: git, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

After branching, the default changelist of WebStorm will take a long time to update, and git for Windows takes up a lot of CPU.

What could cause it? How to fix this problem?

My operating system is Windows 10, and the version of WebStorm is 2020.1.3

The reason is to execute this command

```
git -c crediential.helper= -c core.quotepath=false -c log.showSignature=false --ignored -porcelain -z --
```

Comment: It makes sense to update to 2020.3 version.